# Understanding why two TF-IDF vectors are similar

Tags: text, scikit-learn, nlp

I want some feedback on an approach to understanding the results of TF-IDF vectors, and possibly alternative approaches.

Right now, I have two corpuses of text. The goal is to find which documents in each corpus is most similar.

When I find a match that is intereseting, I want to know why, so I've implemented a simple function called `why_match()`, but I'd like to help to know if it is a valid approach.

It works like this:

```
def why_match(doc_vector_a, doc_vector_b, sklearn_tfidfvectorizer):
    distance = abs(doc_vector_a - doc_vector_b)
    nearest_words = np.array((distance != 0) & (distance < 0.0015))
    vocab = np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
    keywords = vocab[nearest_words]
    return keywords
```

The idea should be to return all keywords which are closer than some threshold (0.0015), and not 0 (most likely because the word isn't in either document).

Is this a valid way to 'explain' closeness in TF-IDF? My results are decent, but it seems to attach a great deal of value to very generic words, which is unfortunate, but very telling for my task.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is one way of explaining vector similarity. Your approach calculates the Manhattan distance (or L1-distance) between two TF-IDF vectors. Just like the Euclidean distance (or L2-distance), the Manhattan distance is overly influenced by "large" values in one of the vectors. A more commonly approach is therefore to measure the *angle* between two vectors using cosine similarity.

A minimal example for using cosine similarity would be as follows:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

sim = 1 - cosine(doc_vector_a, doc_vector_b)
```

The `1 - cosine(...)` is necessary because the `scipy` function returns the *distance* rather than the *similarity*.